# Purpose of the Easter baskets?

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

In The Simpsons Trapped Out, I placed 3 Easter baskets in my town. I can see eggs inside them (one has one, the second has two, the third is empty), and clicking them does nothing. How can I use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have.

Or, put another way, you don't.

Which of those two statements is "more correct" depends upon your perspective. By placing the baskets, your friends can now place 100 of their corresponding eggs (i.e. pink eggs for pink baskets, blue eggs for blue baskets) into your baskets (receiving 50 of the other color in return, although not from your stocks -- so don't worry!). Each basket can hold 400 eggs, and once it is full [the basket disappears](http://simpsonstappedout.wikia.com/wiki/Egg_Baskets) and the 400 eggs are added to your inventory.

That you see eggs in them means someone (or multiple someones) has placed eggs, but the total count has not yet reached 400, and therefore you must simply continue to wait.

**Update:** Having finally filled a basket up myself, I have to correct this post: It is *not* automatic as I had implied, but rather a floating egg icon will show up on the filled basket and you'll be able to collect them (and the basket will disappear) by tapping. Which is actually consistent with the gameplay, so if that's how you read my post originally then it's all good.